# maven tomcat plugin or cargo plugin?

Tags: maven-2, spring-mvc, maven-cargo

The spring source code examples use maven tomcat plugin and i am able to run these projects using the command `mvn tomcat:run` but what i dont see the application is not deployed in local tomcat server("C:\apache tomcat\webapps\")..

And how it is different from cargo plugin? (In this case when i ran the command `mvn cargo:redeploy`, i see the application deployed in the location "C:\apache tomcat\webapps\")

If i add cargo plugin to the POM of spring examples (like mvn-showcase,petclinic)..will it screw up the things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The spring source code examples use maven tomcat plugin and i am able to run these projects using the command mvn tomcat:run but what i dont see the application is not deployed in local tomcat server("C:\apache tomcat\webapps\")

The command [`tomcat:run`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) starts an **embedded** Tomcat, it doesn't deploy an application to your local Tomcat (why does it matter anyway?).

> And how it is different from cargo plugin?

Cargo is a container agnostic tool so you could configure it to use a remote container, a locally installed container, an embedded container (as long as implementations are provided for a given container) and still use an unified API (or set of commands).

> In this case when I ran the command `mvn cargo:redeploy`, I see the application deployed in the location "C:\apache tomcat\webapps\"

Cargo doesn't support running [Tomcat+6.x](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Tomcat+6.x) in embedded mode. So you are very likely using it with a locally installed container and your app gets physically deployed on it.

> If i add cargo plugin to the POM of spring examples (like mvn-showcase,petclinic)..will it screw up the things?

It won't screw up anything, why would it.

Comment: Pascal, Thanks for your reply..Somehow i disliked using tomcat embedded container.I will add cargo plugin to these examples..Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can use tomcat maven plugin and deploy it to external tomcat server. 
see [this link](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-SNAPSHOT/tomcat6-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) for all the available goals. tomcat-run will start a embedded server but tomcat:deploy works for external tomcat.